# How to swap up/down arrow key behaviour and C-n/C-p behaviour in emacs *w3m* buffer

Tags: emacs, customization, w3m

I am trying to find a quick **elisp fix** that makes **w3m** under Emacs swap default behaviour of **UP/DOWN** arrows (moving between hyperlinks in loaded page), with **C-n/C-p** (moving to next and previous line in the page). These key-bindings must only apply when focus is in a **w3m** buffer.

Intuitively this configuration would work better for me since I am currently tuned into **cua-mode** behaviour, particularly in those situations when performing a quick **shift-select copy/paste** operation.

Moving between hyperlinks with **C-n/C-p** will become a very explicit action, whereas the default mapping to **UP/DOWN** comes as an unhelpful surprise; at least to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be easy of course to remap bindings local to a mode and invoke them via a hook...

```
(add-hook 'w3m-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (local-set-key "\C-n" 'w3m-next-anchor)
        (local-set-key "\C-p" 'w3m-previous-anchor)
        (local-set-key '[up] 'previous-line)
        (local-set-key '[down] 'next-line)))
```